# Is there a Windows tool for desktop divider (treating one display as two smaller displays)

Tags: windows, desktop, display

I use two large LCD displays. I would like to treat one of the displays as two smaller displays.

It would be the opposite of merging two displays to become one continuous desktop space.

For example, when I move one application to one of the smaller virtual display areas and click "Maximize", it would maximize to the size of that virtual display, not to the size of the LCD monitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out these ones:

1. [SplitView](http://www.splitview.com/download)

   SplitView is a great program that splits windows on your screen and allows you to easily manage and display split windows. The program does not necessarily create two separate displays. But does give the user a much easier way to split their windows and move them on screen. Once installed two additional buttons will be added to each window at the top left that can be clicked to split the window.
2. [GridMode](http://jgpaiva.donationcoders.com/gridmove.html)

   GridMode is another excellent program and a free alternative that enables users to split their screen into grids. Once split up the user can drag windows into the grids and easily manage windows several different ways. To drag to a grid move the window to one of the edges of the screen.
3. [nVidia Grids](http://www.nvidia.com)

   Users with nVidia video cards installed with 3.0 desktop manager and  later can use the nVidia Grids to break up their windows. To do this right-click on the nVidia settings, open nVidia Desktop Manager, and click Edit Display Grids. Once you've edited the display grids you can move windows to the grids by holding down Alt and dragging the window to a grid or right-click on the window bar, click nVidia Options, and Maximize to grid.

Reference: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000894.htm

**UPDATE**: nVidia recently (2010) withdrew nView (they only support it for the more expensive Quadro video cards). It seems the only game in town is [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/)

Comment: It would be good to include whether freeware, paid etc.