# Full screen an application on half of the window?

Tags: windows-7, window

Is is possible to full-screen an application (like chrome browser, or Word for example) and only use 50% of the window space (either the left or right side).

The reason I ask such a question is that I love how clean my work-space gets  when you full screen applications. It can really help focus. But I'd still like to use side by side programs.

- You lose the window borers
- You lose the status bars
- You lose the start menu (usually)
- You lose the menu bars, and window controls..

Full screening an application is very nice. But I only need it to be half the width of my monitor.

I've attached 2 images. They show what side by side non full screen does, and what I would like it to do (if possible).

[image]

---

[image]

---

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, I don't think there's a foolproof (non-application-specific) way to do this. I wish there was, I'd definitely use it!

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this post with the same question, the only thing I have come across is software options.

Then while referencing a page which shows a few options I found another SuperUser post, so I will just link to that instead: [Is there a Windows tool for desktop divider (treating one display as two smaller displays)](https://superuser.com/questions/317713/is-there-a-windows-tool-for-desktop-divider-treating-one-display-as-two-smaller)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to toggle removing the windows interface up top but perhaps just making your taskbar hide automatically would be enough?

Right click on task bar and click properties. Then check the below box for auto-hiding.

[image: taskbar autohide]

You could also try changing the width of the borders here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6283-borders-changing-width-suite-your-needs.html

Alternatively, I would suggest getting a second monitor if you like side-by-side comparisons. Then you would be able to full-screen each app on each screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications when it full screen mode are designed specifically to do this, it is called distraction free mode, it is mainly targeted at user who want to read rather than do work.

You could deploy a second monitor but if you activate full screen mode it may do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a virtual OS such as virtual pc.  You can run the program in fullscreen via a smaller video on your desktop.   Any virtual pc program should work in theory.   I would advise you to keep process intensive programs on the main drive and run less stress based programs on the VPC.

Comment: Virtualization nor running VM was never mentioned in the question. Please consider editing your answer in the relevance to the question.

Comment: It's very relevant.   Full screen apps in  vm then tile the vms