# Show two full-screen applications on the same monitor

Tags: windows, fullscreen

I've got Windows 7, two applications and one wide-screen monitor.

The applications can work only in *full-screen mode*. But I need to vertically split the monitor so I can watch both applications at the same time.

What is the best solution?

*Edit:*

It is not a duplicate because other users want to *Maximize* their windows, and the software in other answers can't organize *full-screen mode* applications.

Example: How to run to two instances of Internet Explorer (or other browser) in *full-screen* mode (F11) on the same monitor?

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/317713/is-there-a-windows-tool-for-desktop-divider-treating-one-display-as-two-smaller

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, sorry, but I think it's not a dublicate. Just updated this question

Comment: Originally marked duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility

Comment: Gotcha. Then the 'best solution' (IMO) is to get a second monitor.

Comment: Maybe there's a less radical solution? :)